# Struct array data pass issue - swiftui

Tags: arrays, xcode, swiftui, struct

I'm creating register app where first view contains list of fields and second view contains picker fields with data obtaining from GET API. I have created a submission button on thrid view with POST API function. I have trouble passing the data from first and second view to thrid view to submit the data.

First View:

```
struct test3: View {
   
    @State var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section() {
                        TextField("Number", text: $VM.mobileNumber)
                        TextField("Email", text: $VM.email)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        TextField("Name", text: $VM.name)
                        TextField("Gender", text: $VM.gender)
                        TextField("Address", text: $VM.address)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        DatePicker("Birthday", selection: $VM.dateofBirth, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    Section() {
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            test2()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Next")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second View:

```
struct test2: View {
    @State var stateId: States? = nil
    @State var districtId: Districts? = nil
    @State var constituencyId: Constituency? = nil
    
    @StateObject var getStates = StateViewModel()
    @StateObject var getDistricts = DistrictsViewModel()
    @StateObject var getConstituency = ConstituencyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section() {
                    Picker("States*", selection: $stateId) {
                        Text("Select a State").tag(nil as States?)
                        ForEach(getStates.states, id: \.id) {
                            states in Text(states.value).tag(states as States?)
                        }
                    }
                    .task {
                        do {
                            try await getStates.fetchStates()
                        } catch {
                            //should display error.localizedDescription to user.
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    Picker("District*", selection: $districtId) {
                        Text("Select a District").tag(nil as Districts?)
                        ForEach(getDistricts.districts, id: \.id) {
                            districts in
                            Text(districts.value).tag(districts as Districts?)
                        }
                    }
                    .task(id: stateId, { //This will run when the selected continent changes
                        districtId = nil
                        getDistricts.districts = []
                        //Since a new continent was selected makes the selected country nil and empty the list
                        guard let stateId else { //Proceed if the continent isn't nil
                            return
                        }
                        //Get the new countries list
                        do {
                            try await getDistricts.fetchDistricts(stateId: stateId.id)
                        } catch {
                            //should display error.localizedDescription to user.
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                    Picker("Constituency*", selection: $constituencyId) {
                        Text("Select a Constituency").tag(nil as Constituency?)
                        ForEach(getConstituency.constituency, id: \.id) {
                            constituency in
                            Text(constituency.value).tag(constituency as Constituency?)
                        }
                    }
                    .task(id: districtId, { //This will run when the selected continent changes
                        constituencyId = nil
                        getConstituency.constituency = []
                        //Since a new continent was selected makes the selected country nil and empty the list
                        guard let districtId else { //Proceed if the continent isn't nil
                            return
                        }
                        //Get the new countries list
                        do {
                            try await getConstituency.fetchConstituency(districtId: districtId.id)
                        } catch {
                            //should display error.localizedDescription to user.
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                    NavigationLink {
                        test4()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Next")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

third View:

```
struct test4: View {
    @StateObject var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()
    @StateObject var VM1 = NewVoterViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form {
                Section {
                    Button {
                        VM1.makePostAPI(id: VM.id, name: VM.name, address: VM.address, aadharNumber: VM.aadharNumber, email: VM.email, dateofBirth: VM.birthdayString, mobileNumber: VM.mobileNumber, stateId: stateId?.id ?? 0, districtId: districtId?.id ?? 0 , constituencyId: constituencyId?.id ?? 0)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Submit")
                }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

POST API call has mandatory parameter `countryId` and `stateId` `districId` and `constituencyId` has different struct array which i'm unable to pass the data to the submission view.

POST API call:

```
class NewVoterViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    
    //****--POST API CALL--****//
    func makePostAPI(id: Int, name: String, address: String, aadharNumber: String, email: String, dateofBirth: String, mobileNumber: String, stateId: Int, districtId: Int, constituencyId: Int, countryId: Int = 1) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://janasenanriconnectwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Voter/CreateVoter") else {
            return
        }
        
        print("Making api call..")
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body: [String: AnyHashable] = [
              "name": name,
              "gender": "male",
              "dateofBirth": dateofBirth,
              "mobileNumber": mobileNumber,
              "aadharNumber": aadharNumber,
              "email": email,
              "address": address,
              "countryId": countryId,
              "stateId": stateId,
              "districtId": districtId,
              "constituencyId": constituencyId,

        ]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil  else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewVoter.self, from: data)
                print("SUCCESS: \(response)")
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

GET API call:

```
struct States: Hashable, Codable{
    let id: Int
    let value: String
}

@MainActor class StateViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var states: [States] = []
    func fetchStates() async throws {
        let url = "https://janasenanriconnectwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MasterData/getStates"
        self.states = try await URLSession.shared.decoded(url: url)
    }
}

struct Districts: Hashable, Codable { 
    let id: Int
    let value: String
}
@MainActor class DistrictsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var districts: [Districts] = []
    
    func fetchDistricts(stateId: Int) async throws {
        let url = "https://janasenanriconnectwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MasterData/getDistrict?stateId=\(stateId)"
        
        self.districts = try await URLSession.shared.decoded(url: url)
    }
}

struct Constituency: Hashable, Codable { //Rename to something that represents the object, this isnt a list it is a single object.
    let id: Int
    let value: String
}
@MainActor class ConstituencyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var constituency: [Constituency] = []
    
    func fetchConstituency(districtId: Int) async throws {
        let url = "https://janasenanriconnectwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MasterData/getConstituency?districtId=\(districtId)"
        
        self.constituency = try await URLSession.shared.decoded(url: url)
    }
}
```

I posted similar issue but i guess i was not clear presenting my issue. I'm new coder, please point me some pointers and assist me if my code is incorrect.

I'm expecting to pass the data from first and second view to the thrid view and which is passed from struct array and GET api struct type. Please help me with the issue.

Comment: To solve your issues, you need to understand how to use `ObservableObject`.
You **must** have only **one** `@StateObject ...` for your models at the highest view hierarchy, and pass them to other views.
Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: Can you explain the issue @workingdogsupportUkraine I have read the manage data in apple developer but i couldn't relate it to my scenario

Comment: You have hundreds of line of code, I cannot sift through all of that code.
 As a first observation, you have `@State var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()` in `test3`, then you have
 `@StateObject var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()` in `test4`, really, that is not what the link I showed you
 tells you to do.
 Read again, how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

 especially, how to pass a model/ObservedObject from one view to another.

Comment: Can I have a explanation for just `stateId` `districtId` property, so I can understand for the rest of the properties. @workingdogsupportUkraine because those are the real issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode that shows how to use a `ObservableObject` and pass it to other views.
Similarly, the pseudocode shows how to pass your `@State var stateId: States?` etc...
from `test2` to `test4`.

Assuming you have `class PersonInfoViewModel: ObservableObject`.
In `test3` declare `@StateObject var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()` and `VStack {...}.environmentObject(VM)`,
to pass the model to the other views, in particular to `test2`.

In `test2` just have `@EnvironmentObject var VM: PersonInfoViewModel` to receive the model.

To pass the `@State var stateId: States?` etc...
to `test4` use `test4(stateId: $stateId, districtId: $districtId, constituencyId: $constituencyId)`.

```
 class PersonInfoViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var mobileNumber: String = ""
     @Published var email: String = ""
     @Published var name: String = ""
     @Published var gender: String = ""
     @Published var address: String = ""
     @Published var dateofBirth: Date = Date()
     @Published var aadharNumber: String = ""
     var birthdayString: String {
         return ".dateofBirth as string"  // <-- todo
     }
 }
 
 struct test3: View {
     @StateObject var VM = PersonInfoViewModel()  // <-- here

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
            ....
        }.environmentObject(VM)  // <-- here
    }
 }
 
 struct test2: View {
     @EnvironmentObject var VM: PersonInfoViewModel  // <-- here
     ....
 
    test4(stateId: $stateId, districtId: $districtId, constituencyId: $constituencyId)  // <--- here
 }
 
 struct test4: View {
     @EnvironmentObject var VM: PersonInfoViewModel // <--- here
     @StateObject var VM1 = NewVoterViewModel()
     
     // --- here
     @Binding var stateId: States?
     @Binding var districtId: Districts?
     @Binding var constituencyId: Constituency?
    .....
 }
```

Note, in `class NewVoterViewModel: ObservableObject{...}` you do not get a `NewVoter`
as the response from the server, you get something completely different.
So your JSON decoding will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the help @workingdogsupportUkraine It worked. I got one question. what if I have two views that uses `class PersonInfoViewModel: ObservableObject` to bind the values. should I just use`.environmentObject(VM)` to the other view too?

Comment: usually you don't have to, unless it is in a `.sheet` etc..., then you need to add to that view.